# SocketException When reading part of the available data in Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I have a UdpClient sending small datagrams back and forth to another client.  I'm trying to pull one datagram at a time out of the Socket's buffer by using

```
udpClient.Client.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags);
```

and I'm having two problems.  The first problem is when receiving, I'm pulling one byte less than is available from the socket and I get a SocketException:

> A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself

This is the case when (trying to pull 6 bytes of the available 7):

```
Client.Available = 7
buffer = byte[1024]
offset = 0
size = 6
socketFlags = SocketFlags.None
```

The underlying socket buffer size is something big, like 8k.  I found that if I set size=Client.Available, I do not get this error.  For some reason, it doesn't like that I'm trying to pull only 6 of the 7 bytes out of the socket.

To get around this, I used the overload

```
udpClient.Client.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags, out SocketError socketError);
```

and ignored the "error".  This let me receive 6 of the 7 bytes.

However, this gave way to the second problem, which is:

When I pull 6 of the 7 bytes available on the socket, the buffer flushes, and Socket.Available = 0.  What baffles me is this code was working maybe 6 months ago, but on a different machine.  I've done some reading and I guess the SocketException can be caused by the OS accessing the socket, but I was using Windows 7 64-bit both then and now.  Has anyone ever experienced a problem like this, or might have some knowledge to shed light on the subject?  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to read the whole datagram at once. If you don't, at best the remainder is lost. It's not a byte stream like TCP.

Comment: What happens if two datagrams arrive before the socket is polled?  Is the first one thrown out or will they both be waiting in the buffer, assuming the buffer isn't full?

Comment: @Alng If they both fit they are both buffered, and if they don't, it's the second one that is liable to be lost, not the first.